# Rock 4se: Raspberry Pi 7” touch screen does only work with Android 7 (but not 9 and 11)

Tags: touchscreen

I try to run Rock 4 SE with the 7" Raspberry Pi touch screen on Android. For this I tried different official rock android versions (e.g. from https://wiki.radxa.com/Rock4/downloads). Android 7 works fine, but Android 9 and 11 don’t.

The description of Android 9 in the posted link says that it supports the touch screen, but for me it does not work. Maybe someone knows what’s wrong or why it might not work?

I assume that the screen is correctly connected, because it works fine with Android 7, but nevertheless I’ve added photos of it (maybe something there is fishy).

Thanks a lot

[image]

[image]

Comment: You set-up is very special. I assume you won't find many Rock 4 SE users here, so it is unlikely you will get an answer. I assume you would have a more focused audience in the [Radaxa forum](https://forum.radxa.com) or on XDA forums.